# pandas timedelta with float argument

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

pandas [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) documentation states that the `value` input parameter should be of the following types:

`valueTimedelta, timedelta, np.timedelta64, str, or int`

However, when I use a floating point number for `value`, it seems to work fine.  For example:

```
pd.Timedelta(1.234234, "h")
```

yields

```
Timedelta('0 days 01:14:03.242400')
```

This functionality is said to be based on numpy's `timedelta64` which indeed raises an error when passed a floating point argument.

So, is it always safe to use a floating point number for `value` with pandas `Timedelta`?  Is the docstring simply wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to note that:

`pd.Timedelta(1.234234, "h")`

Is equivalent to:

`pd.Timedelta(hours=1.234234)`

And later on in the documentation it states:

> **kwargs ... Values for construction in compat with datetime.timedelta. ... python ints and floats.

So, I believe it should always be safe to use floating point numbers, and that the docstring is probably outdated.